# How an I create a model population?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I need to crate a model population for my Math fair and this is what I have. I need some help with it

-I want to find out the size of a population by using a natural exponential function

-When I have this function, I will be able to know the original population and them find out how many people are after a certain time.

-P(T)=P(0)e^kt

I have this information:

[image]